# Get user from API call in django tastypie to create an object

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have the following model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
...
class Experiment(models.Model):
""" Experiment class """
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and the following resources

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        excludes = ['id', ]
        allowed_methods = ['get', ]



class ExperimentResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Experiment.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'experiment'
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        excludes = ['id', ]

    def hydrate_user(self, bundle):
        bundle.obj.user = bundle.request.user
        return bundle
```

But when I create a new Experiment using post request and ApiKeyAuthentication the user field remains blank, even when I hydrate the user field.

I'm using django-tastypie 0.11

Answer (score 0):

That's because bundle.obj.user is not User model, but SimpleLazyObject.

Try to replace,

```
def hydrate_user(self, bundle):
    bundle.obj.user = bundle.request.user
    return bundle
```

with,

```
def hydrate_user(self, bundle):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=bundle.request.user.pk)
    bundle.obj.user = user

    return bundle
```

Or, if user is not always in request, make sure you send valid resource_uri for User model, for example, `/api/v1/user/1/`

Comment: I implemented you propose and it didn't work. I don't send the user model in the request because I want the final user doesn't have access to modify that field. I tried to do something like [this first tip](http://blog.gingerlime.com/2012/keep-your-hands-off-my-tastypie/) but I think this is not working because I'm using ApiKeyAthentication.